# Handle EditText in android using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am trying to develop an app on android and I have run in to some problems with EditText and a new activity.

I have an activty for which I want three EditText items. In each EditText I read a string from a JSONObject which I put in the EditText. The purpose with the activity is to be able to edit what is in the EditText items.

The for me strange thing is that when I put three EditText items in the layout file, there are six lines when I open the activtity. I do not understand why it behaves like that.

Here is the Activity class together with its fragment and the xml-file.

EditDate.java:

```
public class EditDate extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_edit_date);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        EditDateFragment editDateFragment = new EditDateFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.edit_date_container, editDateFragment).commit();
        }

}
```

EditDateFragment.java:

```
public class EditDateFragment extends Fragment {
    private JSONObject outerObject;

    public EditDateFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        int POSITION = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION", -1);
        EditText editDay = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_day);
        EditText editMonth = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_month);
        EditText editYear = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_year);
        if (POSITION >= 0) {
            try {
                String day = getDay(POSITION);
                String month = getMonth(POSITION);
                String year = getYear(POSITION);
                editDay.setText(day);
                editMonth.setText(month);
                editYear.setText(year);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("POSITION IS NEGATIVE");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_date, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundleSavedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(bundleSavedInstanceState);
        outerObject = MainActivity.usrObject;

    }

    private String getDay(int POSITION) throws JSONException{
        JSONArray list = outerObject.getJSONArray(MainActivity.LIST);
        JSONObject dayObject = list.getJSONObject(POSITION);
        JSONObject date = dayObject.getJSONObject(MainActivity.LIST_DATE);
        String day = date.getString(MainActivity.LIST_DAY);
        return day;
    }
    private String getMonth(int POSITION) throws JSONException{
        JSONArray list = outerObject.getJSONArray(MainActivity.LIST);
        JSONObject dayObject = list.getJSONObject(POSITION);
        JSONObject date = dayObject.getJSONObject(MainActivity.LIST_DATE);
        String month = date.getString(MainActivity.LIST_MONTH);
        return month;
    }
    private String getYear(int POSITION) throws JSONException{
        JSONArray list = outerObject.getJSONArray(MainActivity.LIST);
        JSONObject dayObject = list.getJSONObject(POSITION);
        JSONObject date = dayObject.getJSONObject(MainActivity.LIST_DATE);
        String year = date.getString(MainActivity.LIST_YEAR);
        return year;
    }
}
```

fragment_edit_date.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.shootingapplication.EditDateFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_edit_date"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/edit_date_container"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_day"/>
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_month"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_year"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

acticity_edit_date.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.shootingapplication.EditDate">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_edit_date" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And content_edit_date.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.erikbylow.shootingapplication.EditDateFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_date" />
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Three EditText items gives 6 lines]

I have tried using

```
android:singleline="true"
```

and I have tried different layouts, but I do not really understand it. I have not worked that much with fragments so I have probably done something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: please post your activity's XML layout code

Comment: I have updated it now.

Comment: where is the XML layout code for `<include layout="@layout/content_edit_date" />` ?

Comment: which layout contains R.id.edit_date_container

Comment: fragment_edit_date.xml

Comment: post fragment_edit_date.xml

Comment: please clarify your code

Comment: fragment_edit_date was there, wrote day by mistake, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95805/discussion-between-droidmind-and-erik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have set R.layout.fragment_edit_date as the view of the layout and to the same layout you added the fragment which has the view same as that of activity in the line

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.edit_date_container, editDateFragment).commit();
```

change your `acticity_edit_date.xml:` as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.shootingapplication.EditDate">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and the activity code as below

```
public class EditDate extends AppCompatActivity { 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acticity_edit_date.xml);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    EditDateFragment editDateFragment = new EditDateFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, editDateFragment).commit();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.edit_date_container, editDateFragment)
    .commit();
```

First param of `add(R.id.edit_date_container, editDateFragment)` should be a Id of view where you want to add the Fragment, not a Id of layout which you want to add.

Firstly, delete this line in activity layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_edit_date" />
```

and put something like that:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/my_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

then, in your Activity write this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.my_container, editDateFragment)
        .commit();
```

Comment: I have tried that now and I get an exception:

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006b (com.example.erikbylow.shootingapplication:id/my_container) for fragment EditDateFragment

Comment: Make sure you have FrameLayout with id: my_container in your activity layout

Comment: I had to change to 

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_date);

of course. :)